# Radio Tray Unity panel icon color change

Tags: icons, customization

Thanks to the Linux Action Show I've discovered the awesome Radio Tray panel applet and am loving it.  The only problem I have with it is that the icon is blue and everything else in my system tray is white.  How would I go about changing the icon color?  Thanks in advance from a new Ubuntu fan!

Answer (score 0):

Radio tray icons are placed in different folders, but the one you are interested on is named `radiotray_on.png`, whose location may be found by dropping `locate radiotray | grep .png` in a terminal in order to know all the locations of the Radio Tray ICons.

The one which manages the notification area status icon for the Radio Tray application is set inside of the folder: `/usr/share/radiotray/images` specifically called `radiotray_on.png`.

I suggest you to run nautilus with administrative rights (`gksudo nautilus`) over that folder in order to open the icon in gimp or any other software of your choice on which you can change the hue, saturation and curves of the icon, then save it (remember to backup) and restart Radio Tray in order to the changes to take effect (you need just to re-play your current radio station if already playing).

Illustration here: (check the radiotray notification's area icon and the edited radiotray_on.png highlighted with inverse colors in nautilus)

[image]

Here is a copy of the image that you can use if you don't feel like editing the icon manually (right click, save as, etc.):

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the excellent instructions, but I replaced the radiotray_on.png with the custom one you provided but there was no change to the icon in the system tray.  Should I reboot my system to make the change in the icon stick?

Comment: It should change just by restarting the radio station playback. If it didn't try shutting radiotray down and starting it again. I don't think you need to reboot but maybe you must change a different icon in the list provided by the locate radiotray | grep .png. Check it out, there are several icon sizes, which can be handling your system tray icon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because I had loaded two themes, ZorinLight and ZorinDark, and had chosen the wrong icons for the theme. They were loaded in a separate directory, /usr/share/icons/ZorinLight or ZorinDark/(size)/status/(icon).png. The theme I used was ZorinDark but the icons were set (for cinnamon) in dconf Editor. They were under org /cinnamon /desktop /interface /iconTheme. When I changed the setting from ZorinLight to ZorinDark, the Icons became visible on the tray.

I initially tried to change them in the /usr/share/radiotray/images directory but that didn't work. Setting a theme with unique icons may be the cause of your problem.